# Ссылка & reference и * p reference?

Tags: c++, указатели, ссылки

Вопрос возник из-за убитого моего ответа из

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267199/Как-используется-и-выглядит-в-коде-Си-ссылка-на-указатель/1267218](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1267199/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%A1%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/1267218)

Вопрос :

> Прочитал про ссылки и указатели в С++ Как выглядят ссылки, ссылки на указатели, и как они применяются в Си?

Ответ :

> ```
> // обычная переменная
> int i = 1 ;
>
> // указатель
> int * const p = & i ;
>
> // ссылка
> * p ;
>
> // по ссылке присвоить значение
> * p = 2 ;
> ```

Проверяем тип переменных с помощью `typeid` и создаём новые переменные такого-же типа с помощью `decltype`.

```
# include <utility>
# include <iostream>
# include <typeinfo>
int main ( ) {
    int i = 0 ;
    int * p = & i ;
    int & s = i ;
    std::cout<<"typeid(i).name()=="<<typeid(i).name()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"typeid(p).name()=="<<typeid(p).name()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"typeid(s).name()=="<<typeid(s).name()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"typeid(*p).name()=="<<typeid(*p).name()<<std::endl;
    // decltype(s) s2 ; // error: 's2' declared as reference but not initialized
    // decltype(*p) pp2 ; // error: 'pp2' declared as reference but not initialized
}
```

печатает :

```
typeid(i).name()==i
typeid(p).name()==Pi
typeid(s).name()==i
typeid(*p).name()==i
```

Почему компилятор говорит, что `*p` это ссылка, а все гуру данного сайта, что нет.

Почитал английский вопрос : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48388510/generally-is-dereference-pointer-expression-results-a-reference-type/48388647#48388647 и ничего не понял *(попозже дошло)*.

> Dereferencing a pointer yields an **lvalue** expression of the pointed-to type designating the object or function pointed to. It does **not** yield a *reference*. `*pi` is an *lvalue* of type `int`.

Comment: Потому что таков алгоритм работы `decltype`. Если выражение `E` — это lvalue типа `T`, то тип `decltype(E)` должен быть `T&`. [dcl.type.decltype](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype): «otherwise, if `E` is an lvalue, `decltype(E)` is `T&`, **where `T` is the type of `E`**». `decltype` не всегда выводит в точности тот тип, который имеет выражение.

Comment: `decltype(i) i2 ;` - пашет нормально, уже не lvalue? @wololo

Comment: Я вам привёл ссылку на стандарт с описанием алгоритма. В вашем случае, `i` — это имя переменной. Алгоритм выведения типа заканчивается **раньше**, до проверки на `lvalue` дело не доходит.  Если в `decltype` передать просто имя переменной, то он выведет её тип

Comment: Тот вопрос был про язык С, в котором типа "ссылка" нет.

Comment: `decltype((i)) i2 ;` - теперь говорит, что ссылка. Это `decltype` так мутит? @wololo

Comment: В этом случае `decltype` применяется к выражению `(i)`.

Comment: Да. Если так `decltype(i)`, то внутри `decltype` просто имя переменной. Согласно алгоритму в данном случае должен быть выведен тип этой переменной. А если так `decltype((i))`, то внутри уже сложное выражение; применяется часть алгоритма про `lvalue`.

Comment: Вообще вопрос хороший. Было бы неплохо, если бы кто-нибудь взялся написать подробный ответ про категории значений, типы и их взаимосвязь. А также про `decltype` и зачем в принципе алгоритм его работы таков, что в данном случае он навешивает ссылку. Но сам я за написание такого ответа не возьмусь :)

Comment: @wololo покритикуйте мой ответ, попробуем написать совместно

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что есть две "ортогональные" системы понятий:

`value_category`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Это `lvalue`, `rvalue` и так далее

И типы:
Это `reference`, `value`, `pointer`

Эти две системы связаны между собой списком (список в статье, я приведу выдержку):

```
int  i;  i - lvalue типа int
int& i;  i - lvalue типа int
int* i; *i - lvalue типа int
```

слева стоят три разных типа, а справа - одна и та же `value_category`

Вы в своих рассуждениях отождествили `value_category` "lvalue" c `reference` (строка 2), в этом состоит ошибка.

Аналогичный набор силлогизмов:

```
Корова кушает траву
Зайчик кушает траву
Коза кушает траву
```

X кушает траву, кто такой X? Вы уверенно говорите "зайчик!", хотя правильный ответ "не знаю, кто-то из этих троих - это может быть корова, зайчик или коза".

Comment: Если всё, что можно изменять "грубо скажем" это lvalue. А ссылка тоже относиться к lvalue. У ссылки-то совсем другая категория?

Comment: Получается `int & i; ` - это **ссылка™** как тип C++,  а `lvalue reference` это категория типов, где ссылка занимает почётное место? Как тогда разделить в разговоре эти две ссылки?

Comment: @AlexGlebe, _выражения_ (expression) характеризуются 1) категорией значения (value category), 2) типом (type). Например, пусть объявлены переменные `short a = 0, b = 0;` и есть выражение `a+b`. Так вот, _категория значения_ у этого выражения — `prvalue`, а _тип_ — `int`. Примеры типов: `int`, `float`, `int*`, или даже `int&`. Такой тип `int&` называют _ссылочным_ типом, или если более детально `lvalue reference to int`. Да в _названии типа_ используется слово `lvalue `, но в данном случае это слово не имеет никакого отношения к категориям значений (value category).

Comment: @AlexGlebe, более мудрёный пример. Объявляем переменную `int a = 0;`. Теперь используем её в выражении `static_cast<int&>(a)`. 1) категория значения — `lvalue`, 2) тип выражения — `int` (просто `int`, без ссылки). Тип выражения никогда не бывает ссылочным.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, ещё пара примеров. `int a = 0; ++a; long b = 0; ++b;`. В данном случае выражения и `++a`, и `++b` — это `lvalue`, но имеют разные типы `int` и `long` соответственно. С другой стороны выражения `a + 1` и `++a` имеют одинаковый тип `int`, но разные категории значений `prvalue` и `lvalue` соответственно. Тип и категория значения — это не эквивалентные понятия. Во фразе `lvalue reference to T` слово `lvalue` просто часть названия типа, не категории значения.

Comment: Получается : `int i ; int & l = i ; int * p = & i ;` делаем `l = 0 ;` получаем присваивание в lvalue reference, предоставленную типом ссылка из `l`. А если `*p = 0 ;` то это тоже присваивание в lvalue reference. `l` - это ссылка, а `*p` - нет. ? @wololo

Comment: @AlexGlebe, с одной стороны `l` — это имя переменной, но здесь `l = 0 ;` это самостоятельное, полноценное _выражение_. Его value category — `lvalue`, его тип — `int`. Здесь происходит не `присваивание в lvalue reference`, здесь _значение объекта_, который обозначается/идентифицируется `lvalue`, стоящим слева от оператора присваивания, заменяется значением, полученным из _выражения_, стоящего справа от оператора присваивания.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, тут `*p = 0 ;` аналогично. `*p` — это выражение, value category которого — `lvalue` и тип которого — `int`, и значение **объекта**, который это `lvalue` обозначает/идентифицирует заменяется новым значением.

Comment: @AlexGlebe wololo все правильно говорит. Добавлю, что тип переменной (в противоложность типу выражения) похоже вообще ни на что особо не влияет. Кроме `decltype`.

Comment: @AlexGlebe, попробуйте посмотреть на всё это под следующим углом. Где-то там в памяти расположен _объект_. Он имеет тип, размер, адрес. Для манипулирования объектом язык предоставляет удобные идентификаторы/имена. Например, имя не ссылочной переменной — это пример такого идентификатора. Когда имя переменной используется в выражении, то оно подменяется на `lvalue`. `lvalue` — это такая _абстракция_, чтобы как-то обозначить тот объект, который расположен где-то там в памяти. Аналогично со ссылочными переменными. По сути, это ещё одна разновидность имён/идентификаторов для  объектов...

Comment: ... Когда вы используете ссылочную переменную в выражении, она также, как и обычная переменная подменяется на `lvalue`, на некоторую абстрактную сущность, идентифицирующую сам объект. Результат выражения  `*p` — это также `lvalue`, т.е. _нечто_, что обозначает, тот объект, адрес которого хранится в `p`.

Comment: Короче говоря `*p` - это `lvalue`, которая ссылается на переменную. А `s` - это ссылка, которая ссылается на переменную.

Answer (score 3):

**Выражения [никогда](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#type-1) не имеют ссылочные типы.** Их могут иметь только переменные.

Также важно помнить, что `typeid` игнорирует ссылочность и cv-квалификаторы (т.е. const, volatile).

Также, в `decltype` встроена специальная обработка переменных. Хотя имя переменной одновременно является выражением, если дать `decltype` переменную, то он выдаст именно тип переменной, а не тип выражения.

Также, будучи примененным к выражению, `decltype` добавляет к его типу `&`, `&&` или ничего, в зависимости от категории выражения (lvalue, xvalue, prvalue соответственно). Поскольку выражения сами не могут иметь ссылочные типы, конфликтов не возникает.

Чтобы заставить `decltype` обработать имя переменной именно как выражение, его нужно взять во вторую пару скобок.

Рассмотрим примеры. Пусть мы имеем:

```
int x = 1;
int &y = x;
int *p = &x;
```

| Код | Тип переменной | Тип выражения, категория выражения |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `x` | `int` | `int`, lvalue |
| `y` | `int &` | `int`, lvalue |
| `*p` | Это не переменная | `int`, lvalue |
| `42` | Это не переменная | `int`, prvalue |

Ну и соответственно:

- `decltype(x)` = `int` (тип переменной)
- `decltype((x))` = `int &` (тип выражения `int`, плюс `&` означающее категорию lvalue)
- `decltype(y)` = `int &` (тип переменной)
- `decltype((y))` = `int &` (тип выражения `int`, плюс `&` означающее категорию lvalue)
- `decltype(*p)` = `int &` (тип выражения `int`, плюс `&` означающее категорию lvalue)
- `decltype(42)` = `int` (тип выражения `int`, категории prvalue соответствует отсутствие амперсандов)

Comment: Я понял, что `decltype` и `typeid` - ничем не помогут. Вся проблема возникла из-за бюрократии. Ссылка как тип против ссылка как lvalue.